# I'm having problem to load some image from db and css in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, web

I just made a project in laravel, some functions just worked normally, but in one .blade, the data didn't show up and the .css didn't work.

```
<div class="row row-centered">
        @foreach ($profils as $profil)
        <div class="col-md-4" >
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <center>
                    <div class="card-img-top bg-secondary">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/foto/'.$profil->foto_img) }}" width="150 "> 
                    </div>   
                </center>
              <div class="card-body" style="padding: 10px;">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $profil->nama_pendaftar }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $profil->email }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $profil->kontak }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

But, it worked well in my teams laptop (firefox).

Comment: Try refreshing that problematic page using `Ctrl + F5`.

Comment: Try outputing the count first to see if you've got anything in $profils. i.e. $profils->count()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try these

- Clear your browser cache / run using incognito mode
- Try running `php artisan view:clear`
- Are you extending view, if yes is it already the right view
- Check if the css is load successfully using your browser developer tools